# Parsing a weird malformed ini

Tags: php, ini

I have a really broken/weird INI file that looks like [this](http://pastie.org/pastes/5539368/text).

```
RowID=11668
Name=SCNA DaCe
PPA
Relation=Family
RowID=31999
Name=PCA

RowID=11593
Name=CRMLEVEL
Relation=Family
```

If possible, end up as

```
array("11668" => array("name"=> "SCNA DaCe", "relation"=>"Family", "ppa"=>true));
```

Linebreaks are separated based on  `RowID` instead of a proper `[section]` and I have no idea how I can read this, any tips on where to start?

There is inconsistent casing, certain things don't have values (like `PPA` by itself on a line), not all `key=vals` are defined for each case.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For something like this, an array of objects comes in handy.

http://www.laprbass.com/RAY_temp_dylan.php

```
<?php // RAY_temp_dylan.php
error_reporting(E_ALL);
echo '<pre>';

$str = <<<END
RowID=11668
Name=SCNA DaCe
PPA
Relation=Family
RowID=31999
Name=PCA

RowID=11593
Name=CRMLEVEL
Relation=Family
END;

// SIMULATE READING WITH file()
$arr = explode(PHP_EOL, $str);

// COLLECT THE NORMALIZED DATA HERE
$out = array();
$obj = new stdClass;

// USE AN ITERATOR ON EACH ROW
foreach ($arr as $row)
{
    // SKIP BLANK LINES
    $row = trim($row);
    if (empty($row)) continue;

    // FOR EACH ROWID CREATE A NEW OBJECT
    if (FALSE !== strpos($row, 'RowID'))
    {
        // SAVE THE OLD OBJECT
        $out[] = $obj;
        $obj = new stdClass;
        $obj->RowID = end(explode('=', $row));
    }

    // FOR REMAINING ELEMENTS THAT ARE KEY-VALUE PAIRS
    if (FALSE !== strpos($row, '='))
    {
        $key = current(explode('=', $row));
        $val = end(explode('=', $row));
        $obj->$key = $val;
    }

    // FOR REMAINING ELEMENTS THAT ARE NOT KEY-VALUE PAIRS
    else
    {
        $obj->$row = TRUE;
    }
}
// SAVE LAST ELEMENT AT EOF
$out[] = $obj;

// DISCARD THE ZERO "STARTER" ELEMENT
unset($out[0]);
var_dump($out);
```

Answer (score 0):

You would have to roll your own custom solution to parse this INI file as PHP's built in [parse_ini_file](http://php.net/parse-ini-file) is based on PHP's own php.ini format constraints. So it has to be valid PHP.

For your purposes if the requirements are as simple as key/value pairs on each line with the exception of the one-off stranded value as a default boolean true then you could do something like the following.

```
function my_parse_ini($ini_file_name) {
    $ini = file($ini_file_name, FILE_IGNORE_NEW_LINES);
    $return = array();
    $row = null;
    foreach ($ini as $key => $value) {
        if ($value == '') {
            $row = null;
            continue;
        }
        @list($k, $v) = explode('=',$value);
        if ($v === null) {
            $v = true;
        }
        if ($row === null) {
            $row = $v;
            $return[$row] = array();
            continue;
        }
        $return[$row][$k] = $v;
    }
    return $return;
}
/* usage */
var_dump(my_parse_ini('test.ini'));
```

This would output the following for your sample ini file....

```
array(2) {
  [11668]=>
  array(4) {
    ["Name"]=>
    string(3) "PCA"
    ["PPA"]=>
    bool(true)
    ["Relation"]=>
    string(6) "Family"
    ["RowID"]=>
    string(5) "31999"
  }
  [11593]=>
  array(2) {
    ["Name"]=>
    string(8) "CRMLEVEL"
    ["Relation"]=>
    string(6) "Family"
  }
}
```

Comment: RowID=31999 should be it's own array, with a name of PCA. That is one of the issues, there is inconsistency all over the place :(

At this point I'm somewhat considering trying to regex RowID=* into [*] and just trying to parse it that way

Comment: You stated that line breaks separate the RowIDs. You said nothing about the possiblity of a RowID coming without a leading line break.